# Prolog subBag(x, y) tests whether x, considered as a bag, is a subbag of y

Tags: prolog

I currently working on some prolog problems, one is "subBag(x, y) tests whether x, considered as a bag, is a subbag of y". My code doesn't work at all and always true. Here is my code.

```
delete(X,[],[]).
delete(X,[X|T],T).
delete(X,[H|T],[H|Result]):-
   delete(X,T,Result).

subBag([],[]).
subBag([],[H|T]).
subBag([X|S],[H|T]):-
   member(X,[H|T]),
   delete(X,[H|T],Result),
   subBag(S,Result).
```

Thank you.

Comment: Want a hint? [`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=select%2f3) is probably going to help you solve this.

Comment: Your code doesn't work? Give concrete cases what you expect and what does not work. At least, it succeeds for `subBag([a],[a,b]).`

Comment: If I try a wrong case, the output is true. for example subBag([1,1,2],[1,2]) will give me true

Comment: I change the inductive step to
   `subBag([X|S],[H|T]):-
      member(X,[H|T]),
      delete(X,[H|T],[H|Result]),
      subBag(S,Result).`
It works finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a subbag? I take that to mean, all the items in the subbag are present in at least the same quantities as they are in the containing bag. To state it inductively, let's break it into two cases: the case where I have an empty list. Is that a subbag? Yes, of any list:

```
subbag([], Bag) :- is_list(Bag).
```

Now, the inductive case. Let's break the subbag into an item and the rest of the subbag. If this item can be removed from the containing bag, and the rest form a subbag of the remainder from the containing bag, then we have a subbag. Like so:

```
subbag([X|Subbag], Bag) :-
    select(X, Bag, RemainingBag),
    subbag(Subbag, RemainingBag).
```

The magic predicate [`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=select%2f3) is a hugely useful utility here, allowing you in one statement to say `X` is in `Bag`, and the rest of the bag is in `RemainingBag`. This kind of situation seems to come up all the time in processing lists in Prolog. (Note that in the SWI Prolog documentation, there is often a little orange `:-` icon next to the name, which will take you to the source code for that predicate, in case you've been given a stupid requirement not to use a built-in predicate by a clueless professor.)

I want to warn you that the efficiency of this solution is not great, but I actually think the nature of this problem might just be that way. The number of solutions you'll obtain from an query (like `subbag(X, [1,2,3,4,5])`) is going to be large; I found it to be essentially the number of permutations of a set, using the OEIS (sequence [A000522](https://oeis.org/A000522)).

Comment: @Pan no problem! always try to take list problems apart with a base-case/inductive case analysis, and you'll be on the right track. Same for any recursive data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand completely how your code should work, but i think that there is for sure too much splitting into head and tail in places where it is not necessary.

Maybe this predicate will help you to solve your problem.

```
isSublist(Sublist,List) :-
    append([_,Sublist,_],List).
```

This predicate uses append/2 build-in predicate, [read about it here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/2)

Comment: we are not allow to use build in function and I think the difinition for subbag is different from sublist/subset.